# Electric field due to bound charge on surface of dielectric material

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, dielectric

I got stuck on a step in Example 4.8 of Griffiths. It places a charge $q$ a distance $d$ above an infinite linear dielectric material.

**The Problem**

It states the the field due to the bound charge $σ$ is $-σ/2e$. However, I would've expected it to be $σ/2e$ since the normal vector should be facing upwards in the $z$-axis as that is the direction the dielectric faces and σ=P⋅n.

This is with the context that we are trying to solve for σ by finding E due to all charges, including the point charge q and the surface charge at that particular point.

Could someone explain why it is negative?

Comment: You don't say in which point you are looking for the this field. If it is above the charge and the charge is positive and you look for the $z$-component then that would be positive, but all those things are not specified in your question...

Answer (score 0):

If $q$ were positive, then its field at the dielectric will point in the negative $z$ direction. But $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \hat{\mathbf{z}}$, so $\mathbf{P} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is negative. Therefore the induced surface bound charge will be of opposite sign to $q$. In general, the polarization/bound charge in linear dielectrics will arrange themselves to oppose the external applied field, reducing the total field for a given amount of free charge. This is why dielectrics enable capacitors to store more free charge at the same potential difference.